# get distance of lat/lng point from database

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
        vac.vacancy_id              AS vacancy_id,
        vac.title                   AS vacancy_title,
        vac.slug                    AS vacancy_slug,
        vac.company_name            AS vacancy_company_name,
        vac.company_latitude        AS vacancy_company_latitude,
        vac.company_longitude       AS vacancy_company_longitude,
        cat.slug                    AS vacancy_category_slug,
        (
            6371 *
            acos(
                cos( radians( :latitude ) ) *
                cos( radians( vac.company_latitude ) ) *
                cos(
                    radians( vac.company_longitude ) - radians( :longitude )
                ) +
                sin( radians( :latitude ) ) *
                sin( radians( vac.company_latitude ) )
            )
        ) AS distance
FROM
        vacancies vac
JOIN
        vacancies_categories cat
    ON
        vac.vacancy_category_id = cat.vacancy_category_id
WHERE
        vac.subdomain = :subdomain
    AND
        distance < :distance
    AND
        vac.company_latitude IS NOT NULL
    AND
        vac.company_longitude IS NOT NULL
```

This fetches all vacancies that are in circular distance around an address.

It **works** when I **remove** the following line:

```
    AND
        distance < :distance
```

But when I add this piece of code, it does not work. But I want to set a max. distance.

PHP:

```
$stmtSelectVacancies = $db->prepare($querySelectVacancies);

$stmtSelectVacancies->bindParam(':latitude', $latitude);

$stmtSelectVacancies->bindParam(':longitude', $longitude);

$stmtSelectVacancies->bindParam(':subdomain', $subdomain);

$stmtSelectVacancies->bindParam(':distance', $distance);

$stmtSelectVacancies->execute();

// and so on...
```

I also tried the HAVING-clause before the WHERE-clause (HAVING distance < :distance) but that also does not work.

Anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible in MySQL (or most other databases) to reuse an alias defined in a `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause.  This has to do with the alias not yet being available at the time the `WHERE` clause is evaluated.

MySQL has one handy feature which is an overloaded `HAVING` operator, which can be used like a `WHERE` clause.  Also, this `HAVING` operator *can* use aliases.  So, you may try moving the check on the distance alias to a `HAVING` clause:

```
WHERE
    vac.subdomain = :subdomain AND
    vac.company_latitude IS NOT NULL AND
    vac.company_longitude IS NOT NULL
HAVING
    distance < :distance;
```

If for some reason you don't like this approach, then the alternative would probably be to just repeat the entire expression for `distance` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: it works! I had the HAVING-clause before the WHERE-clause, but putting it after it works! Thanks!